# VBA Referring to a cell using Sheet Name not working properly

Tags: vba, excel

**Summary:** I am writing a macro that takes names from many different sheets in an excel file and compiles them together on a "master list", but I'm having trouble with referencing a cell on another sheet.

**The Problem:** When I refer to a specific cell using the sheet name as reference with `Sheets("MasterList").ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)`, nothing gets picked up. However, when I remove `Sheets("MasterList")` the macro works fine (the macro is currently on "MasterList" at the time which is the only way this would work). Also, the spelling for the name of the sheet was correct in my code.

**Question:** Why is this happening? The logic behind the code seems sound, and I'm spelling my sheet name correctly.

**Code:**

```
Do              

   If Sheets("MasterList").ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = firstName Then        'IF FIRST AND LAST NAMES MATCH, EXIT THE CHECK

          Exit Do

   End If

   On Error Resume Next

   Cells.Find(What:=lastName, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
   LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
   MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Loop Until Err.Number > 0
```

Comment: Activecell is a property of the Excel Application object, not of a worksheet.  It represents the active cell in the currently  Active Window.

Comment: +1 As usual Nicely explained question. Two things besides what Tim/Chris mentioned. 1) `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT` Throw it out of your code. Use of OERN should be avoided unless you are using it as "Proactive" programming. 2) I would recommend using this link which explains on how to use `.Find` and `.FindNext` http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Comment: @SiddharthRout as usual, helpful material :D +1. The find tutorial will be really helpful for me in the future. About getting rid of OERN, I'm not sure how the find function would still work if it DIDN'T find what it was looking for, but I'm sure this is explained in your tutorial :p

Comment: @MikeKellogg: Yup the If Statement `If Not cl Is Nothing Then` as shown by chris and also mentioned in the blog takes care of that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ActiveCell` is a property of the `Application` object, not a `Sheet`.

There is only one `ActiveCell`, and it is the active cell on the currently active sheet.

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do.  But in general you should avoid `Select` and `Activate` with this sort of code.  Use instead somthing like:

```
Dim wsMasterList as Worksheet
Set wsMasterList = Thisworkbook.WorkSheets("MasterList")  ' assuming the vba code is in the workbook containing MasterList
```

To track the last used cell in MasterList use a variable like

```
Dim rMasterList as Range
Set rMasterList = wsMasterList.Cells( ...  ' Specify the cell you want
```

Then use `rMasterList.Offset(0, 1)` to refer to cells relative to that cell

Searching on MasterList use:

```
Dim cl as Range
Set cl = wsMasterList.UsedRange.Find( ... )
If Not cl Is Nothing Then
    ' cl will be Nothing if the search term is not found
    ' ...
```